# How would i loop this Scanner in java?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

```java
package javaapplication97;

import java.util.Scanner;    

public class JavaApplication97 {    

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);    

        if (s1.hasNextInt())
           System.out.println("This is an int");    

    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have idea about `for`  and `while` loops? [--> The while and do-while Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) AND [--> The for Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: Please format correctly .

Comment: @Darius  I believe it is, 'Will you please do my homework for me'?

Comment: There are multiple ways to 'loop this scanner' depending on what you are trying to accomplish, What are you trying to accomplish by looping it?

Comment: no i just cant figure out how to use the "for" and "while" loops for this.

Comment: haha actually never mind i figured it out, and i didn't even need to loop the code xD

Comment: @user2291565 Just try something out and then ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

i think you mean this

```
import java.util.*;

public class test{

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        while(true){
            System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
            Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);    

            if (s1.hasNextInt()){
                System.out.println("This is an int");
            }
            else if(s1.nextLine().compareTo("stop")==0){
                break;
            }
            else{
                System.err.println("this is not an int");
            }
            System.out.println("---------");
    }
}
```

Comment: Loop will never stops. You need some mechanism to stop the loop.

Comment: if you would itergrate in a bigger program, you should properly lay it in Thread